# C# WinForms - Drag Drop TreeView in VS 2013 Update 3 not work

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, treeview

I Have Winforms and crate drag drop for my tree view using [Drag Drop Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9391/Dragging-tree-nodes-in-C) in code project.
this worked before I upgrade my project to `VS 2013 update 3` but when project upgrade to VS 2013 I can not start drag in tree view.
I so confused for this complicated problem
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this steps:

1. You must first set AllowDrop=true;
2. Set Event ItemDrag
3. Set Event DragDrop
4. Set Event DragEnter
5. Set Event DragOver

If your tree drag drop worked before and now not work I think it must be for your data structure that checked in DragDrop Event or some other event of drag drop